# Understanding the Definition of Lebesgue space (as it is given in a book of Katok/ Hasselblatt)

Tags: measure-theory

On page 733 of *Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems* by Anatole Katok and Boris Hasselblatt I found the following definition of *Lebesgue space*:

> > **Definition A.6.4.** A measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ with finite $\mu$ is called a *Lebesgue space* if it is isomorphic to the union of $[0,a]$ with Lebesgue measure with at most countably many points of positive measure.

I really have problems to understand this definition, especially what is meant with "union of $[0,a]$ with Lebesgue measure with at most countably many points of positive measure".

May you please explain that to me?

Edit: **An addition**

Within the same book one can find the following paraphrase on the top of page 136:

> > For some applications the appropriate notion of a measure space is a *Lebesgue space* (Definition A.6.4), that is, a space isomorphic up to a set of measure zero to an interval with Lebesgue measure with at most countably many "atoms", that is, points of positive measure, added.

Nevertheless, I have problems to understand that but I added this paraphrase here in order to give you more material.

With regards

math12